# Difference between "super" and "supra"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between the syllabales "super" and "supra"? An example would be in the usage of "supranatural" / "supernatural".

Comment: They have different Latin roots (super, supra) with very similar meanings. A dictionary should explain cases where there is a difference in meaning (most dictionaries seem to think supranatural and supernatural mean the same thing).